# What does "reversible" mean in the statement of Kolmogorov's criterion?

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

For a discrete-time Markov chain, [Kolmogorov's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_criterion) is often stated as:

> If such and such property holds for the transition probabilities, then the Markov chain is **reversible**.

But the definition that I know for reversible is that the chain satisfies $\pi(x)P(x, y)=\pi(y)P(y, x)$ for all $x, y$, and for some probability distribution $\pi$. In other words, it doesn't apparently mean anything to say that "the chain is reversible", only the the chain is "reversible *with respect to a given probability distribution*".

Under the conditions of Kolmogorov's criterion, with respect to *which* probability distributions is the chain reversible?

Answer (score 0):

Under this particular statement of Kolmogorov's criterion, reversibility is "with respect to" the transition probabilities from the transition matrix $P$.

- Suppose that our Markov chain is time-homogeneous, so that $P_{ij}(t)
     = P_{ij}$, i.e. the probability of transitioning from state $i$ to $j$ at time $t$ is independent of the time, where $P_{ij}$ are the
  entries of the chain's transition matrix.
- A positive recurrent Markov chain with transition matrix $P$ and
  stationary distribution $\boldsymbol{\pi}$ is time-reversible if the
  reverse-time stationary Markov chain has the same distribution as the
  forward-time stationary Markov chain, i.e. if $P_{ij} = P_{ji}$ for
  all pairs of states $i,j$.
- The "time-reversibility" equations $\pi_i P_{ij} = \pi_j P_{ji}$ for all pairs $i,j$ serve as useful algebraic ways to check whether a chain is time-reversible or not. If a Markov chain is time-reversible, it necessarily satisfies these equations, but we do not need to take these equations as the definition per se. They have the interpretation that: for each pair of states $i,j$, the long-run rate of transitioning from $i$ to $j$ is the same as the long-run rate of transitioning from $j$ to $i$ (i.e. frequency of such transitions). This is because $\pi_i$ is the long-run proportion of time that a Markov chain will spend in state $i$.

Source and helpful reading: http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/stochastic-I/stochastic-I-Time-Reversibility.pdf

Hope I interpreted your question correctly.

Comment: What I mean is, the definition of reversibility includes a $\pi$. When we say that a chain is reversible under the conditions of KC, what is $\pi$?

Comment: $\pi$ is the stationary distribution of the Markov chain. One definition of a stationary distribution is that when a Markov chain is initialized in its stationary distribution, it remains in its stationary distribution.

Comment: But a Markov chain can have several stationary distributions.

Comment: Suppose that the Markov chain is irreducible. Then it is positive recurrent if and only if there is a probability vector $\boldsymbol{\pi}$ (positive, summing to $1$), such that $\boldsymbol{\pi} = \boldsymbol{\pi} \boldsymbol{P}$, and then this $\boldsymbol{\pi}$ is the *unique* stationary distribution. http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/stochastic-I/stochastic-I-MCII.pdf

Comment: In the case of time-reversibility, the stationary distribution is unique (see Theorem 2.1 and its proof in the link in the above comment). So there is no confusion about which stationary distribution we need to consider here.

Comment: I don't think that's true. You can come up with an easy example of a non-irreducible chain which satisfies Kolmogorov's criterion by just having a non-irreducible chain which has no closed loops.

Comment: To be clear I meant for the case of irreducible Markov chains. This is not a terrible assumption because if the chain is reducible, we can separate the chain (see section on canonical form of transition matrix) and analyze the chain separately based on its communicating classes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain#Canonical_form

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your chain satisfies the Kolmogorov Criterion. Fix a state $x_0$. For every other state $x$ choose a path  $R(x)=\{x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},x\}$  from $x_0$ to $x$ such that the reversed path  $\hat R(x):=\{x,x_{n-1},\ldots,x_1,x_0\}$ has positive probability;   that is, such that $\hat\rho(x):=P(x,x_{n-1})\cdots P(x_2,x_1)P(x_1,x_0)>0$. The concatentated path $R(x)\{x,y\}\hat R(y)$ (which is a cycle) has (by KC) the same probability as its reverse; that is,
$$
\rho(x)p(x,y)\hat\rho(y) =\rho(y)p(y,x)\hat\rho(x).
$$
Defining $\pi(x):=\rho(x)/\hat\rho(x)$, you have reversibility with respect to $\pi$. [The existence of a path like $\hat R(x)$ amounts to an assumption of irreducibility.]